# How to not evaluate the third part of a ternary operator unless necessary

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

For my program, I need the functionality of the below line of code. If the condition evaluates to true, I need the expression if false to not be evaluated due to a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
Bobject VARvalue = (args.Length < 2) ? Zero : new Bobject(args[2]);
```

EDIT: I was not specific on the goal of this line. The goal is to check if `args[2]` exists in the code, and if it doesn’t, make the variable a different value, as `args[2]` would throw an exception.

Comment: That's already working correctly. What you've got is an off-by-one error -- an array that has length 2 only has data at indexes 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your condition to be false, `args.Length` has to be EQUAL TO `2`, or greater.

If it is `2`, accessing `args[2]` will throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` because the only available indexes are `0` and `1`.

If you want the SECOND item in the `args` array, you have to pass in an index of `1`, because array indexes are ZERO-based.
`Bobject VARvalue = (args.Length < 2) ? Zero : new Bobject(args[1]);`

Or at least modify your condition to `args.Length <= 2`. Im not so sure which will address your specific goal, but hope this sets you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are 0-based, so the second item is at index 1, not 2:

```
Bobject VARvalue = (args.Length < 2) ? Zero : new Bobject(args[1]);
```